# How about flipping a jcombobox?

Tags: java, jcombobox

How can I flip a `jComboBox` so that the popup menu button is on the left rather than on the right?

I have tried:

```
setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

but here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the drop-down arrow is controlled by the `ComboBoxUI` associated with the `JComboBox`.  Generally, if you want to change this behavior, you have to create your own implementation of `ComboBoxUI`.  Fortunately, for your specific need there is another way.  The default `ComboBoxUI` is coded to place the arrow on the right by default, but it will place the arrow on the left if the component orientation is changed to right-to-left:

```
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
comboBox.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

[image]

As you can see, this will affect the orientation of the component as a whole, but it does not affect the orientation of the list box items within the combo box.  To make this adjustment, call `applyComponentOrientation` on the `ListCellRenderer` associated with the component.  If you have a custom renderer, you can just call the method on that object.  With the default renderer, it's a little trickier but still possible:

```
ListCellRenderer<? super String> defaultRenderer = comboBox.getRenderer();
ListCellRenderer<String> modifiedRenderer = new ListCellRenderer<String>() {
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends String> list, String value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Component component = defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(
                list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        component.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        return component;
    }
};
comboBox.setRenderer(modifiedRenderer);
```

[image]

Finally, if your combo box is editable, you'll likely need to use `applyComponentOrientation` on the editor component as well.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help, but only the button got positioned at the left, not even flipped, leaving the combobox in a bad appearance

Comment: @MichaelShenouda in that case, it would help if you could edit your question and clarify what you mean by 'flipped'.  Your question currently only mentions positioning the popup menu button on the left instead of the right.

Comment: I have reedited my question, I think you are going to understand me now.

Comment: @MichaelShenouda I see, on your OS the arrow button is asymmetrical, whereas on my OS it is symmetrical.  You can try using `applyComponentOrientation` on the `JComboBox` instead of `setComponentOrientation`, it might work, but I can't test it

Comment: @MichaelShenouda You're welcome!  I thought it might work from the javadocs but I wasn't sure since I couldn't test it.